# how to get client ip in soap web service method?

Tags: python, web-services, soaplib

I'm using `soaplib` library for SOAP web services,
I want to access client's IP Address when client request has been made in my web service method.

```
class HelloWorldService(DefinitionBase):
    @soap(String, Integer, _returns=Array(String))
    def say_hello(self, name, times):
        # here I want to Access client's IP Address
        pass
```

Here is my Server's pseudo code...

```
server = make_server('localhost',
                     7789, 
                     HelloWorldApplication(Application([HelloWorldService], 'hello')))
print "serving http://localhost:7789/hello?wsdl"
server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 1):

From the `make_server` I'm assuming you're using [`BaseHTTPServer`](http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html) or one of the packages that builds on top of it.

In your request handling code, you should be able to find a reference to the client socket.  Use that to get [`getsockname()`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.getsockname) and retrieve the client IP and TCP source port.

For example, if the socket reference was in the base class as `socket`, you could:

```
class HelloWorldService(DefinitionBase):
    @soap(String, Integer, _returns=Array(String))
    def say_hello(self, name, times):
        # here I want to Access client's IP Address
        print "Client IP:", self.socket.getsockname()[0]
```

My hacked-up example, to retrieve the IP of the listening socket on the server: (this is not the client socket!)

```
>>> httpd = make_server('', 8000, simple_app)
>>> dir(httpd)
['RequestHandlerClass', '_BaseServer__is_shut_down', '_BaseServer__shutdown_request', '__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', '_handle_request_noblock', 'address_family', 'allow_reuse_address', 'application', 'base_environ', 'close_request', 'fileno', 'finish_request', 'get_app', 'get_request', 'handle_error', 'handle_request', 'handle_timeout', 'process_request', 'request_queue_size', 'serve_forever', 'server_activate', 'server_address', 'server_bind', 'server_close', 'server_name', 'server_port', 'set_app', 'setup_environ', 'shutdown', 'shutdown_request', 'socket', 'socket_type', 'timeout', 'verify_request']
>>> dir(httpd.socket)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_sock', 'accept', 'bind', 'close', 'connect', 'connect_ex', 'dup', 'family', 'fileno', 'getpeername', 'getsockname', 'getsockopt', 'gettimeout', 'listen', 'makefile', 'proto', 'recv', 'recv_into', 'recvfrom', 'recvfrom_into', 'send', 'sendall', 'sendto', 'setblocking', 'setsockopt', 'settimeout', 'shutdown', 'type']
>>> httpd.socket.getsockname()
('0.0.0.0', 8000)
```

Getting the actual client IP is a little more involved example, since you don't get a reference to the client socket object until the request handler callback is called.   An example using BaseHTTPServer:

```
import BaseHTTPServer

class Handler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write("Client IP: %s" % self.connection.getsockname()[0])

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(("", 8000), Handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I don't have `soaplib` on a system here to give you a more precise example, but the socket object is tucked away in there somewhere.

Comment: I need client IP Address not server one, `httpd.socket.getsockname()` will return the server's IP Address...  and `DefinitionBase` doesn't have any attribute called `socket` so `self.socket` is AttributeError in `HelloWorldService` class!

Comment: I don't have a copy of soaplib to find the reference for DefinitionBase.  In the BaseHTTPServer client object, the socket object is called connection. self.connection.getsockname() returns the client IP. I'll update the post. You'll have to find the right socket reference in DefinitionBase. It's there somewhere.

Comment: SOAP itself is transport independent and therefore does not know
anything about IP adresses, I'm able to fetch IP Address in `on_wsdl_call` but its in `wsgi.Application` class !!

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
's/self.connection.getsockname()[0]/self.client_address[0]/'
```